# Canon 5D Mark II, bracketed exposures with least number of steps to avoid camera shake?

Tags: hdr, canon-5d-mark-ii, bracketing, multiple-exposure

I'm trying to devise a method where I can take more than just 3 bracketed exposures on the 5D Mark 2 while minimizing the steps to avoid moving or shaking the camera.

This is my current procedure...

**Setup**

- Drive Mode: 2sec
- In Av mode (f/8), take a shot to get the middle exposure: **1/15**
- Switch to Manual, set shutter to -2ev: **1/4**
- Set AEB to +/- 2ev (-,0,+)

**Exposures**

- Release shutter using external cable **(3 shots taken 1", 1/4, 1/15)**
- Move shutter to +2ev from middle exposure: **1/60**
- Release shutter using cable **(3 shots taken 1/15, 1/60, 1/250)**

So, basically, the only time I move the camera is when I dial in +2ev after the first set of bracketed exposures are taken, but it's still enough to cause alignment issues in my shots. Is there any room for improvement?

PS: Since I'm using an external shutter release, is there a way to avoid the 2sec shutter delay? It seems that, in Manual mode, when set to Single or Continuous shooting, AEB does not shoot the exposures automatically; it only seems to work in 2sec delay mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have smartphone you can get an app (such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.dslrremote) that will help you with this. You'll also need a cable, but that can be made pretty cheap.

Comment: I have to say, this is very interesting, thank you for the info.

Comment: I just downloaded DSLR.bot and built a custom DIY infra-red transmitter for my iPhone, and it worked great! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

The magic lantern custom firmware for the 5D2 offers extended exposure bracketing up to 13 shots, so you don't have to alter any settings part way through.

The firmware is loaded from CF card and only lasts until powered down.

Comment: I'm in a motel in Bangor Maine right now shooting 9 bracketed steps with a 5D MkII with the Magic Lantern software. Just do it.

Comment: Magic Lantern Firmware? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki

Comment: Tried this, very cool firmware, tons of options, too many, but definitely suites my needs, thx!